# Making the sum of 5th power of integers, a perfect square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, natural-numbers

Yesterday this question was posed in a contest. It contains pretty easy questions like asking range of $ab+bc+ca$ when $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$, etc.

But this question is something else. I haven't been able to solve this after $4$ hours.

**Question:**
Find, $n$ if
$133^5+27^5+84^5+110^5=n^2$.

I checked answer on calculator, it is $248832$.
I tried all sort of things I can do like trying to factor the expression, converting two of the odd nos. into $(m+n)^5+(m-n)^5$ form. But all in vain.

I hope anyone can help me here.

Comment: Not a very enlightening method but I guess you could try to take the sum modulo different numbers (taking ones which are easy to compute. For example, modulo 27, you get $(-2)^5+0^5+3^5+2^5 \equiv 3^5 \equiv 0 (\textrm{mod }27)$ and use Chinese remainder theorem to get $n \equiv a(\textrm{mod }N)$. You can bound $n$ to then retrieve the answer.

Comment: It seems $248832=12^5$

Comment: @daruma-Isn't that too much to ask when you have 10 minutes at max to solve in the paper?? I also thought of that but would take too much time also won't confirm that the answer is true.

Comment: @Henry- Wow brother, it may work. Let me check. If only this question was MCQ, I would've done it. Just calculated the answer so didn't emphasize much on it.

Comment: Astonishing that you were asked to figure this out by yourself. The fact that the sum of these four fifth powers is equal to a fifth power, $n^2 = 144^5$, was discovered in a paper in 1966 as a counterexample to Euler's conjecture regarding sums of powers. They used a computer, not any analytic techniques. Look up Wikipedia for "Euler's conjecture counterexamples"

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг- Is there really not any way solve this problem??

Comment: This was indeed published by L. J. Lander and T. R. Parkin in 1966, "Counterexample to Euler's conjecture on sums of like powers". Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society (AMS),  as a direct search on CDC 6600. Link: http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1966-72-06/S0002-9904-1966-11654-3/S0002-9904-1966-11654-3.pdf

Comment: I can quickly get $n^2\equiv 24 \Rightarrow n\equiv \{12,18\} \bmod 30$, since Carmichael's $\lambda(30)=4$ so $a^5\equiv a \bmod 30$.

Comment: @Joffan- May you write an elaborated answer??

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг It is indeed true that it was published as a counter-example to a conjecture of Euler, but the difficult part is finding the counter-example, not proving that the sum of the four numbers is a fifth power. Once you are given the numbers, it is trivial to check that the claimed equality is true. The difficult part is finding the numbers in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

*This is less than a complete solution but too long for a comment.*

Suppose $n^2 = a^5 + b^5 + c^5 + d^5$.  Then:

$$n^2 = (a+b)m + c^5 + d^5\quad\quad(1)$$

where:

$$m = a^4 -a^3b + a^2b^2 -ab^3 + b^4$$

Applying $(1)$ with $(a,b,c,d) = (133,27,110,84)$:

$$n^2 = 160m + 110^5 + 84^5 = 2^5(5m + 55^5 + 42^5)$$

Hence $2^5 | n^2$ and so $2^3 | n$.

Also, applying $(1)$ with $(a,b,c,d) = (133,110,84,27)$:

$$n^2 = 243m + 84^5 + 27^5 = 3^5(m + 28^5 + 9^5)$$

Hence $3^5 | n^2$ and so $3^3 | n$.

Combining the above results:

$$2^33^3 | n$$

Comment: It is helpful but I don't see how I will reach the correct answer from this.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Let's make a transformation, to find $n \in \mathbb{N_+}$ such that $133^5+27^5+84^5+110^5=m^5.$

#### Step 1

> Estimate the bound of $m$.

Notice that $$133^5<10 \times 100^5,~~~27^5<1 \times 100^5,~~~84^5<1 \times 100^5,~~~110^5<10 \times 100^5.$$Thus $$133^5<m^5=133^5+27^5+84^5+110^5<22 \times 100^5<200^5.$$
Hence, $$133<m<200.$$

#### Step 2

> Find the unit-digit of $m$.

Since $$m^5 \equiv133^5+27^5+84^5+110^5\equiv3^5+7^5+4^5+0^5\equiv3+7+4+0\equiv 4(\textrm{mod }10) ,$$hence the unitdigit of $m$ is $4.$

#### Step 3

> Find $m$.

Since $$m^5 \equiv133^5+27^5+84^5+110^5\equiv1^5+0^5+0^5+2^5\equiv 0(\textrm{mod }3) ,$$hence $3|m^5$. Further, $3|m$. Therefore, $m=144$ or $174.$ However, since$$m^5 \equiv133^5+27^5+84^5+110^5\equiv0^5+6^5+0^5+5^5\equiv 2(\textrm{mod }7) ,$$ and $144^5 \equiv 4^5 \equiv 2 (\textrm{mod }7)$, $174^5 \equiv 6^5 \equiv 6 (\textrm{mod }7)$,$174$ is not the solution. As a result,$$m=144.$$

Comment: Yes, if you are told that $n$ is a fifth power it becomes fairly easy. But this information was not available to the OP!

Comment: @mengdie- Nope bro this solution is wrong. I wasn't given sum of those numbers is 5th power of some no.

Comment: This method could be generalized to solve OP. Further more, if $n^2 = 144^5 = (12^2)^5 = (12^5)^2$, then $n = 12^5$.